# Stick MYSQL query results into string separated by a comma

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

The first query i am making is for all of the Id's associated with a user:

```
$DBH = getDBH();
$stmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT id FROM list WHERE user = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$userid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($ids);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
```

currently stored in the table is as follow:

```
ID            user

1             example
4             example
7             example
15            example
```

The id's are not known before the query and the amount of id's associated with the user will be continuously growing and shrinking.

So my question is how can i query for these id's and stick them into a string with each id separated by a comma

ex:
1,4,7,15, etc, etc.

**EDIT: USING GROUP CONCAT()**

```
$stmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) as id FROM list WHERE user = ? GROUP BY id");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$userid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at group_concat() function

Plese note that the max length that the string can take is specified by group_concat_max_len() variable and by default is 1024 chars.

You can see yours with this query

```
show variables like 'group%'
```

Comment: i have been looking into it, but i can't seem to get it to work with a prepared query, thanks for the help btw!

Comment: Have you tried to assign an alias to it? select group_concat(id) as ids from table where ...

Comment: yeah thats what i did it looks like this: